# How to execute a command repeatedly and execute another when error throws up without always checking for if conditions?

Tags: javascript, if-statement, exception, try-catch

I have a code like there are only 2 scenarios - the data is of byte format / text format. Only at the kick start or very rarely I may receive text data. Hence i wrote the code like below :-

```
if (message.type === 'utf8') {
   console.log(message.utf8Data);
 }
if (message.type === 'binary') {
    dataStream.write(message.binaryData);
 }
```

Now I wish to refactor the code where by default it takes the binary type and proceeds to

```
dataStream.write(message.binaryData);
```

and if the type is unmatched or error it should execute

```
console.log(message.utf8Data);
```

Please don't suggest any if else condition as it is expensive since dataStream gets execute a couple of hundred times, while text gets executed only or twice during the session. Doing a if check on every data format is cumbersome since every time we waste computation to know the data format.

I checked to execute try...catch on it. But I was not able to get proper results. Kindly someone suggests how to refactor this code to boost performance. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
try {
  dataStream.write (message.binaryData); 
} catch (err) {
  // if an exception occurres print the data instead
  console.log (message.utf8Data); 
}
```

Comment: Again if used to check in every data. I want the function to execute on the go rather than each time checking for the format.

Comment: Well you can just remove the if statement. In that case if an exception occurres during the write the catch will be exacted.

Comment: No bro, does not seem to work. What happens is the message.binaryData returns an undefined; and that's not an error. Hence try loop won't break as it is not an error (undefined being a valid data type) and breaks the application instead!